# Manipulating multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#144 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "name1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#145 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "name2"
  }
}
```

I want to add key and value (for example [distance] = 100;) to the objects in the array. After this I want to sort on the distance values. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get structure such as yours you can do:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0]->id = "2";
$arr[0]->name = "name1";
$arr[1]->id = "4";
$arr[1]->name = "name2";
```

To add "distance" you can do:

```
$arr[0]->distance = 100;
$arr[1]->distance = 200;
```

To sort you can use decorate/sort/undecorate pattern:

```
$arr = array_map(create_function('$o', 'return array($o->distance, $o);'), $arr); // transform array of objects into array of arrays consisted of sort key and object
sort($arr); // sort array of arrays
$arr = array_map('end', $arr); // take only last element from each array
```

Or you can use usort() with custom comparison function like this:

```
function compareDistanceFields($a, $b) {
  return $a->distance - $b->distance;
}
usort($arr, "compareDistanceFields");
```

Comment: Decorate/sort/undecorate pattern works great (and fast)! Thanks!

Comment: Finally someone appreciated it! I learned it from python and tried to sneak it into my few answers to php questions, but people did not like it so far. Probably they didn't want to bother with understanding how it works. usort() is easier but I think that at least in some cases (maybe most?) it might be slower

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array[0]->distance = 100;
$my_array[0]->distance = 101;

usort($my_array, "cmp");
function cmp($a, $b)
{
   if ($a->distance == $b->distance)
     return 0;
   return ($a->distance > $b->distance) ? 1: -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have here is an array of hashes; that is, each element of your array is a hash (a structure containing elements, each of which is identified by a key).

In order to add a key and value, you just assign it, like this:

```
$array[0]["distance"]=100;
$array[1]["distance"]=300;
#and so on
```

PHP hashes and arrays in general are documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Now, in order to sort your array (each of whose elements is a hash), you need to use the "uasort" function, which allows you to define a comparison function; in this comparison function you define the behavior you want, which is sorting on the value of the distance key.

Something like this:

```
// Comparison function, this compares the value of the "distance" key
// for each of the two elements being compared.
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a["distance"] == $b["distance"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["distance"] < $b["distance"]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Once this is defined, you call uasort like this:

```
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

Find more documentation on [uasort here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

Comment: Elements of his array are objects, we need to use `->`, not `[]`

Comment: When I try "$array[0]["distance"]=100;" Result is: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: I think you should use usort() not uasort() ... Association between keys and objects does not seem relevant given in example given by asker.

Comment: First part is completed. Now my array has the distance value and keys.

$i++; 
$array[$i]->distance=$dist;    

Now I have to find out how usort works to compare hunderds of values.